# Adding a NavigationView to panel sencha touch 2

Tags: image, controller, sencha-touch-2

i'm trying to get a navigationView on click on an image , but it does'nt work for me ,the event is fired , but when i try to switch to the about view nothing happened , i'm using a navigationview in order to have a back button ..
My controller :

```
   Ext.define('app.controller.MainController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
config: {
    refs: {
        main: 'Main',
        about: 'About',
        aboutimg: '#aboutimg'
    },
    control: {
        aboutimg: {
            tap: function(img, evt) {
                Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('app.view.About'));
            }
        }
    }
}

 });
```

My about view :

```
  Ext.define('app.view.About', {
extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
xtype: 'About',
 ....
```

Main View:

```
 Ext.define('app.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'main',
requires: [
    'Ext.Img'
],
config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    fullscreen: true,
    defaults: {
        flex: 1
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel'

        },
        {
            xtype: 'carousel',
            flex: 3,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: 'vbox',
                    items: [],
                    dockedItems: [{
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            style: 'background-color: #fff;',
                            layout: {
                                type: 'hbox',
                                pack: 'center'
                            },
                            flex: 1,
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'image',
                                    id:'aboutimg',
                                    mode: 'element',
                                    src: "resources/images/about.jpg",
                                    cls: 'component',

                                },
      ......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to activate the panel you just added which will bring it to front. So, do this inside your "tap" event function:

```
var aboutPanel = Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('app.view.About'));
Ext.Viewport.animateActivateItem(aboutPanel, {
  type : 'slide',
  direction : 'left'
});
```

This should work fine.

Comment: It works thank u , but the back button doesnt display :s do u have an idea ?